# Why emacs opens a menu with the keybinding bound to another command?

Tags: key-bindings, menu-bar

I want to use the command `just-one-space` which is bound to `M-SPC`, see the describe key associated with it:

[image]

Unfortunately, if I press `M-SPC` a menu opens up in Emacs:

[image]

I was expecting to execute `just-one-space`.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The window manager intercepts that key sequence before Emacs can get its hands on it. See e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68619/dealing-with-aggressive-desktop-environments and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66771/how-can-i-override-an-os-keybinding-in-emacs/66820#66820.

Comment: That seems to be the correct duplicate :)

Comment: Just surrender to EXWM. Perhaps you're not aware of it, but you can run EXWM "on top" of GNOME. Meaning that you'll still have the top bar with the date and wifi settings; access the GUI programs you're used to; etc. In other words, you can start a GNOME session and replace GNOME's window manager with EXWM. Indeed, most people use EXWM alone, but that might be too extreme to start with.

Comment: @phils: yes, indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs didn’t open that menu, your operating system or window manager did. Note that the same thing happens to other key combinations, like `M-Tab` (better known as Alt-Tab).

`M-SPC` opens that same menu for all applications in Windows. Linux computers running Gnome have a similar menu bound to the same keyboard shortcut.

Comment: The solution to my problem was found outside of Emacs.

Using the Settings on Ubuntu I did:

    Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > Activate the window menu > Backspace to disable the keyboard shortcut

Comment: Sure, that’s one possible solution.